# Want all links that have 2 attributes, how do you pass 2 attributes?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I know how to pass 1 attribute, but how do I pass 2?

e.g.

```
somerows = soup.findAll('a', target="blank")
```

what if I want all links that have target="blank" and class="blah" ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary to avoid having problems with some attribute names such as 'class':

```
soup.findAll('a', {
    "target" : "blank",
    "class" : "blah",
    "href" : re.compile(...)
})
```

This is mentioned in the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Searching%20by%20CSS%20class).

Comment: in one of the attributes, I am using:  href=re.compile('...')  how can this fit into what you posted?

Answer (score 1):

`soup.findAll('a', 'blah', target='blank', href=re.compile(...))`

Quoth [the BS docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Searching%20by%20CSS%20class):

> The attrs argument would be a pretty
>   obscure feature were it not for one
>   thing: CSS. It's very useful to search
>   for a tag that has a certain CSS
>   class, but the name of the CSS
>   attribute, class, is also a Python
>   reserved word.
>
> You could search by CSS class with
>   soup.find("tagName", { "class" :
>   "cssClass" }), but that's a lot of
>   code for such a common operation.
>   Instead, you can pass a string for
>   attrs instead of a dictionary. The
>   string will be used to restrict the
>   CSS class.

Comment: so just comma seperated? hmm..let me try.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more complicated search, you can also do:

```
key = lambda tag: ...
# or even
def key( tag )
    return len( tag.attrs ) == 2 # for example

soup.findAll( key )
```

See the [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#match-callable).